# User needs execute right to save file in docker container directory

Tags: linux, docker

I want to save and read files from within a running container. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
...
RUN groupadd -g 2000 javagroup && \
    useradd -m -r -u 1000 -g javagroup javauser

RUN mkdir -p /storage && \
    chmod -R 700 /storage && \
    chown -R javauser:javagroup /storage
...
```

It works with the UGO-Rights `700`. But why i have to give execute right to the user? I thought it would be enough if the user has read/write-rights.

Comment: /storage is a *directory*. Without execute permission on it, you wouldn't be able to list it

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

> In Linux, you need the "execute" (-x) right for a directory to be able
> to enter it. Entering a directory means being able to view the
> contents of the directory or access files and subdirectories within
> the directory. The execute right on a directory is independent of the
> rights on the files within the directory. Even if you have read and
> write permissions for a file within a directory, you need execute
> permission on the directory to access that file. This is because
> entering a directory is considered a separate step that must be done
> before accessing the files within. The execute right on a directory
> allows you to traverse the path to the directory and identify and
> select the files in it. Without the execute right, you cannot change
> to the directory and access its contents, even if you have the
> necessary rights to the files within the directory. It is important to
> note that the execute right on a directory is not the same as the
> execute right on an executable. The execute right on an executable
> file allows you to run the file as a standalone program, while the
> execute right on a directory gives access to its contents. In summary,
> the execute right (-x) on a directory is required to enter the
> directory and access its contents, including the files and
> subdirectories it contains.